# How do i make my vb.net application only display the text on the website and ignore the source code

Tags: vb.net

as stated in the title I'm trying to make my vb.net application ignore the source code and only display text is on the website. I'm wanting it to ignore the code pre and the /code /pre
Here is the code I have:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim Str As System.IO.Stream
        Dim srRead As System.IO.StreamReader
        Try
            Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://junkcode.gehaxelt.in/")
            Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse
            Str = resp.GetResponseStream
            srRead = New System.IO.StreamReader(Str)
            RichTextBox1.Text = srRead.ReadToEnd
        Catch ex As Exception
            RichTextBox1.Text = "Content Cannot Be Downloaded"
        Finally
            srRead.Close()
            Str.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub VScrollBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) 

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Use a web browser control to render the content rather than a rich text box.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the downloaded HTML into `HtmlDocument` object

```
Dim htmlDoc As HtmlDocument = new HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(srRead.ReadToEnd)
```

Once the HtmlDocument is loaded. You can use `Body` property to access the Html body. After that you can parse the document as you like.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)